# How to use bochs in ubuntu ?

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, operating-system, bochs

I am making a simple operating system kernel and want to emulate it using bochs. Currently, I am using qemu as my emulator but want to switch over to bochs. I have downloaded and installed bochs in ubuntu but couldn't figure out a way to use it? Can anybody help me with that ? Any links or some way to get me started would be really helpful.

Comment: Question seems to be off-topic because it is too broad.

Comment: How is it too broad? I am just asking for some information to get me started. I am not telling you to list each and every feature of bochs and explain it to me

Comment: I think [Boschs has a manual](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/bochsrc.html), did you read it?

Comment: @m0skit0 Ofcourse, I tried reading it, but couldn't figure out much that's why asked it here.

Comment: So what exactly you didn't understand or you're having problems with? Loading the OS image?

Comment: Yes, I want to load my kernel image onto the emulator. I know that in bochs i have to make a config file first and then only it will work, but in the manual there are tonnes of options available, so I want a very simple minimal example on how to load it onto bochs

Comment: Example configuration file for running open source `MenuetOS` under `Bochs` is available at http://www.goosee.com/menuetos/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use Bochs to run Assembly code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142925/how-can-i-use-bochs-to-run-assembly-code)

Answer (score 0):

I needed the following `.bochsrc` run a minimal boot sector:

```
ata0-master: type=disk, path="main.img", mode=flat,
cylinders=1, heads=1, spt=1
boot: disk
display_library: sdl
megs: 128
```

More details at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32871939/895245